# How do you parse through firebase response of this type?

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart, parsing

So I have read about the other general JSON parsing, although I cannot find a solution for my specific issue. I am pulling the data from firebase using a stream, what is shown in the screenshot is just the response of snapshot.data['04-24-2023'], I would like to parse through the data knowing that everything 'title' will remain constant (levels, listofacceptedplayers, numofplayers, time) except for the host-useremail, this part I would like to pull out and use that information.

[image]

I stored it this way as multiple people can create this list of information for specific dates, and without it this way it was getting overwritten... So how do I pull out the host-email (email part)? And how do I parse through the rest? Thank you!!!

[image]

Comment: I think more specifically, I can easily use the snapshot.data[level].. etc, although how do I capture that 'host-pierre@test.com' and 'host-pip@test.com' to do so?

Comment: Do you have a specific coding question? If so, please post the code you're having difficulty with. Also, we don't know what kind of field `host-pierr@test.com` is - that would be helpful information. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)